# Global variable storage in ACPI

Tags: x86, uefi, acpi

Where are the global variables in an ACPI namespace stored in RAM? Is this region reserved by the BIOS? See example below:

```asl
Scope (_SB.PC00.LPCB.XYZ_)
{
    Device (ABCD)
    {
        Name (VAR1, "foo")
        Method (BAR_)
        {
            VAR1 = "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Where does VAR1 end up being stored, as we have not manually defined a memory operation region for this variable?

Comment: It's the duty of the OS to parse the AML (which is the compiled version of the ASL source, like the one you posted) and execute the opcodes, isn't it? Including NameOp and StoreOp which (I think, not sure, but you get the idea) would be used in the compiled version of `Name` and `=`. I don't think the BIOS is involved. For reference, the ACPI tables are in RAM and the region is marked as reserved when the OS asks for the memory map. But that's not relevant for executing the AML.

Comment: The memory is reserved by ACPI interpreter in the OS or whatever that consumes it (it mabe very well the bootloader or any other custom startup code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where are the global variables in an ACPI namespace stored in RAM?

It depends on the AML interpreter and the OS. For monolithic kernels, it's likely that any indexing of ACPI's global namespace (e.g. a hash table used to find an object from its name), the variable's metadata (name, object type) and the variable's value will all end up in the kernel's heap (in memory allocated by some kind of `kmalloc()` provided by the kernel's memory management).

Comment: Could you provide more details specific to Linux kernel? I want to find out specifics about the behavior e.g. what happens to the AML data when system goes to sleep and wakes up again etc.

Comment: @Hamzahfrq: Sorry - I'm not a Linux developer. For Linux; the only relevant things I know are that Linux uses ACPICA (see https://acpica.org/ ) and that ACPICA requires that the OS provides functions for an "OS Services Layer" during its initialization (e.g. where Linux would provide a function pointer to ACPICA, that ACPICA can use later for its `AcpiOsAllocate()`).